# java - How to stop handle leaks for many simultaneous threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've run into an apparent handle leak, but I'm hoping there's a workaround or that I'm just misunderstanding how the JRE handles Threads internally.

Please note that the answer to this question is NOT "use thread pools and limit the maximum number of simultaneous threads." That doesn't address the underlying problem or possible solutions, especially if a very large number of maximum simultaneous threads is desirable.

If I create and start many threads at once a lot of handles are allocated. This makes perfect sense. However, when those threads all end, most of the allocated handles aren't released.

Handle counts from Process Explorer are given below for:

**Peak** - Maximum handle count after 600 threads are created and running

**Threads Ended** - Handle count after all 600 threads have ended (just leaving the main thread and JVM threads)

```
           Handle Counts
JRE    Peak    Threads Ended
1.4    2632    232
5      3859    259
6      4311    3111
8      4321    3121
```

Two major observations here:

1. JRE 5 and later have substantially higher handle overhead for threads than 1.4
2. JRE 6 and later aren't freeing up handles after threads end

Creating and starting the same or fewer number number of threads repeatedly does not increase the Peak/Ended handle counts (except when using JRE 1.5 which may have another slower leak). Increasing the number of maximum simultaneous threads increases both numbers.

All JREs used for testing are of the Sun/Oracle variety.

GC never comes along and cleans up the mess based on a few days of testing and observing the problem.

Does anybody know how to ensure that the handle resources for Threads are released after use in Java 6 and later without restarting the JVM?

Test code to reproduce the problem is below:

```
public class ThreadLeakTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ThreadLeakTest();
    }

    public ThreadLeakTest()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 600; ++i)
            {
                LeakTestThread testThread = new LeakTestThread();
                Thread t = new Thread(testThread);
                t.start();
            }

            sleepSafe(20000);
        }
    }

    private class LeakTestThread implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {
            sleepSafe(15000);
        }
    }

    private static final void sleepSafe(int sleepTime)
    {
        try
        {   
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat Your answer confirms that the problem, or one very similar, is known to exist and that no official solution exists yet. Other people being aware of the problem is not a solution to the problem. I already made it clear in response to your answer that the suggestions of limiting the target OS and/or changing the programming language aren't acceptable solutions either. Others are welcome to come along at any time in the future with answers that solve the problem.

Comment: You asked for a problem that seems to be a bug. There is no solution to that besides a bug fix. Beyond that there are just workarounds. You wanting a solution does not mean there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known bug, [8154063](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8154063):

> The VM maintains a pool of PlatformEvent objects (which maps to Events on Windows). This pool will grow to the maximum needed by the maximum number of concurrent threads that exist in the VM at one time. We tend to run out of memory to create threads well before we run out of Handles. So during the first sleep only the main thread and a few VM threads exist and the overall handle count is low.
>
> We then start 3000 threads, each of which uses at least 5 Handles (and based on the reported output I'm assuming there is a 6th hiding in the implementation somewhere). Then depending on machine size and scheduling there will be some variance in the number of concurrent threads, but assume all 3000 and it is easy to see where the peak numbers come from.

So there seems no good solution here for Windows, besides reducing the number of threads. Beyond that, a more generic thought: it seems that you are using your hardware for "real" server tasks. If so, consider:

- using an OS that works better with Java then (there is a reason why so many big servers run Linux these days)
- if you have to stay with Windows, you might either consider to use a platform that is "closer" to it, like .NET and C#. Or, you decide for a JVM framework like Akka that achieves its "parallelism" without massive amounts of threads.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report link. That page (8154063) says the bug report is a duplicate of 8145999. However, 8145999 appears to be hidden from public view, so the status is unknown. 8u202 still has the problem well over two years later, so that's not promising.

Comment: I saw that, too. That is why I linked to this one.

Comment: Regarding your edits: cross-platform is required, so I can't lean towards Windows or Linux. Akka doesn't look like a viable option for my purposes. Hopefully your suggestions help others who come across this page.